# low performance when an image with high resolution loaded

Tags: c#

I develop a utility that behaves like "Adobe photoshop". user can draw rectangle,circle,... with mouse pointer and then move or resize it. for this functionality, I assume each shape is a object that stored in a generic collection in a container object. when user wants to change anything I recognise that where he clicked and in behind of scence I select the target object and so on...
this way have a problem when objects in screen is lot or user loads a picture with high resolution.

What's your opinion?

How can I solve it?

Comment: Paint.NET project is an open source and good place to learn such things.

Comment: "Why isn't my application performant?"  "Let me count the possible ways..."

Answer (score 1):

This makes sense because the larger the data set, the more RAM and CPU will be required to handle it.

While performance issues are important to solve, a lot of it may be perceieved performance so something like a threading issue - where you have one thread trying to process the information and you block the UI thread which makes it look like the system is freezing.

There is a lot of information on StackOverflow that you may want to look at

- [C# Performance Optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+performance+optimization)
- [C# Performance Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+performance+best-practices)
- [C# Performance Multi threading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+performance+multithreading)
- [C# Performance Collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+performance+collections) (Since you said you were using a collection)

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that in hi resolution the computer needs to use more the processor, then this occurs, remember that this also occurs in The Gimp, even in Adobe Photoshop.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Use a profiler such as dotTrace and find out which method is the one most called and the one that takes the most amount of time to process. Those are the ones you want to try to optimize. Other than that, you may have to go down to the GPU to try to speed things up.

Answer (score 0):

About these kind of problem, think about parallel extensions : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/concurrency/default.aspx

The more cpu you have, the faster your program is running.

Answer (score 0):

Look into using a performance analyzing tool (such as ANTS Profiler) to help you pinpoint exactly where the bottle necks are occurring. True graphical computations on a high res photo require alot of resources, but I would assume the logic you are using to manage and find your objects require some tuning up as well.

Answer (score 0):

I high-resolution image takes up a lot of memory (more [bits-per-pixel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_depth)). As such, any operation that you do to it means more bits to manipulate.

**Does your program utilise "layers"?**

If not, then I'm guessing you are adding components directly to the image - which means each operation has to manipulate the bits. So if you aren't using layers, then you should definitely start. Layers will allow you to draw operations to the screen but only merge them into the base high-resolution image once - when you save!

**What library from Windows are you using to open the image?**

If you are using [System.Drawing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx) then you are actually using [GDI+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533798%28VS.85%29.aspx) as it is a wrapper on top of it. GDI+ is nice for a lot of things because it simplies tons of operations, however it isn't the fastest in the world. For example using the [Get|Set]Pixel methods are MUCH slower than working directly on the [BitmapData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534421%28VS.85%29.aspx). As there are tons of articles on speeding up operations on top of GDI+ I will not re-iterate them here.

I hope the information I've provided answer some of your questions causes new ones. Good luck!

Comment: i implement the Layers logic with list of objects.
please , describe about Layers that you say.give me an example or link.

Comment: Are you using System.Drawing? Is your GUI in WinForms or WPF?